# React-native bundle iOS issue

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm new to react-native technology and I faced this issue as attached images after I created one component (Header) and tried to use it inside app.js and run iOS emulator. please any advice.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpWys.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd7wY.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xXjK.png)

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjWRm.png)

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVHNl.jpg)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://snack.expo.io/r1tmEEYs4 live basic sample

you return has a little mistake you must change you header codes like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>
        Header Text
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

export default  Header;
```

and you must call that like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


import Header from './components/Header';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header/>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

First you open a terminal and run

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

then

```
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: i got this error Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(SyntaxError: /Users/haya/Desktop/AskDeveloper/src/Header.js: Identifier 'React' has already been declared (6:7)

Comment: can you share u Header.js

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>
        Header Text
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

export default  Header;

Comment: the iOS emulator run fine but after add the Header component inside the app.is the error is appeared.

Comment: i got this error Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Unable to resolve module `./components/Header` from `/Users/haya/Desktop/AskDeveloper/App.js`: The module `./components/Header` could not be found from `/Users/haya/Desktop/AskDeveloper/App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `/Users/haya/Desktop/AskDeveloper/components/Header(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`

Comment: you did call false path it depends on your import check again

Comment: It's working now thank you very much for your time and effort.